# How can i get the String name of day on DatePicker

Tags: android, date, calendar, datepicker

I'm developing a simple app that the user pick some date on DatePicker and return the current day name in some Toast message.
but when I'm trying to do that it has given me a wrong date.
my code:

```
final int day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
datepicker.getDrawableState();

int mounth = datepicker.getMonth();
mounth+=1;

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
String formatDay = new SimpleDateFormat("E").format(cal.getTime());
Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, formatDay, 2000).show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're setting the day of month when you create the Calendar, but you aren't setting the month or year. You need to getMonth() and getYear() of the DatePicker and set those on the Calendar also. Do GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(datePicker.getYear(), datePicker.getMonth(), datePicker.getDayOfMonth(), 0, 0)  instead of Calendar.getInstance(). With getInstance() you are getting a Calendar for the current time, then just changing the day.